# How can I get array of objects instead of array of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

Ok I think this is so simple but I cant get the preferred result so far, so I have an array of objects in my Db like below:

```
"meetingPlans": [
        {
          "date": "2020-11-30",
          "times": [
            {
              "section": "morning",
              "slots": 4,
              "time": "9:00-10:00"
            },
            {
              "section": "morning",
              "slots": 3,
              "time": "10:00-10:15"
            },
            {
              "section": "morning",
              "slots": 2,
              "time": "10:15-10:30"
            },
            {
              "section": "morning",
              "slots": 0,
              "time": "10:30-11:00"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
```

and I need to get the times array separately in one array, I did it in following way but the result is an array of array which isn't satisfying I need a single array:

```
const therapists = useSelector(state => state.therapists.listOfTherapists); // this is the whole object
  let therapistDates = [];
  let therapistTimes = []; 

  const plansArray = therapists.meetingPlans; 
  plansArr.forEach((el) => therapistTimes.push(el.times)); 
  console.log(therapistTimes) //this returns an array of array. but I need a single array
```

how can I get my array?

Comment: `meetingPlans` has one object?

Comment: What is the expected result when there is more than one "date"?

Comment: You can just flatten the array via [Array.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat). Do:  `therapistTimes.flat()`

Comment: @Reyno ty bro, this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this as well:

```
let result=[].concat(...plansArr.map(x=>x.times))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to do that,

```
const res = plansArr.reduce((prev, curr) => {return [...prev, curr.times]}, 
[]);
console.log(res);
```